# wait(NULL) function is not working and parent process is running before child always

Tags: c, linux, unix, process

I have a problem with the following code.
It is like a manual shell program implementation using C on a Unix platform. If the user enters a command, it should execute and return corresponding result.
If the user enters '`&`' at end then the parent process need not wait for child process to complete.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HISTORY_LIMIT 20
#define BUFFER_LIMIT 100
#define MAX_WORDS 50

int count = 0;
char history[HISTORY_LIMIT][BUFFER_LIMIT];

int tokenize(char *str, char **args, int *bRun)
{
    int i, argc = 0;
    char *token;
    if (count == HISTORY_LIMIT)
    {
        // alignHistory();
    }
    // strcpy(history[count],str);
    count++;
    token = strtok(str, " \t\n");
    for (i = 0; token != NULL; i++)
    {
        args[i] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " \t\n");
        argc++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(args[i], "&") == 0)
        {
            *bRun = 1;
            args[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    return argc;
} // end of tokenize function

void handleSignal(int sign)
{
    if (sign == SIGINT)
    {
        // getHistory();
    }
}  // end of handlesignal

int main(void)
{
    char *args[MAX_WORDS];
    char buffer[BUFFER_LIMIT];
    pid_t pid;
    int argc;
    int bgRun = 0;
    if (signal(SIGINT, handleSignal) == SIG_ERR)
    {
        printf("can't handle ctrl-c");
        return 0;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        bgRun = 0;
        memset(args, 0, MAX_WORDS);
        printf("osh>");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_LIMIT, stdin);
        argc = tokenize(buffer, args, &bgRun);
        if (argc == 0)
            continue;

        if (strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0)
            break;
        if (strcmp(args[0], "history") == 0)
            getHistory();
        // else if(strcmp(args[0],"hello")==0)printf("Hi There, How are you ?\n");
        else
        {
            pid = fork();

            if (pid == 0)
            {
                execvp(args[0], args);
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if (bgRun == 0)
                    wait(NULL);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output is:

```
osh>whoami
root
osh>whoami &
osh>root
whoami
osh>root
```

But the required result should be like this (if & is used in command)

```
osh>whoami
root
osh>whoami &
osh>root
whoami
root    
osh>
```

So I have used `bgRun` int variable and assigned 1 if command has 1
but that was not working.  I think it is problem with `wait(NULL)`.  Please save me from this demon.

Comment: Can you please clarify? What is the material difference between the actual and expected output? I can see the obvious difference but it is not clear why one is the correct output and the other is not. And please fix the formatting of your code - hard to read without proper indentation.

Comment: My intention is if & is added in the command then parent need not wait for child process to complete, But if you observe the last four lines of expected vs obtained o/p ..I have entered "whoami & " and clicked enter(as it is '&'  parent should not wait for child so it is executed first and "osh>" is printed before "root") till now everything is fine ..But problem comes in next step where i have entered "whoami" and here parent should wait for child process to execute as i used wait(null) but unfortunately parent is not waiting so i got o/p "osh>" before root

Answer (score 2):

You aren't saying *which* child process to wait for, so the third command (which should not be backgrounded) is considered to complete when the *second* command exits.

oops.

You need to handle `SIGCHLD` and reap background processes when they terminate, and also check that the exited process is the one you're currently running "foreground", and not a background job completing.  `waitpid()` allows you to wait for a specific process.

Comment: And the OP could need to pay attention to children it didn't even know it had (I've done that to a process — deliberately, not accidentally).  You have to check that the `wait()` returned the PID you expected, and if not, decide what to do about it.  Simply blindly ignoring the return value is bad.  Normally, `wait(NULL)` is bad too; you often want to know why/how the child terminated.  And for debugging, it is crucial; you need to capture the PID and status and report them so you know what's going on.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  It would be great if you explain the changes I have to do in my code

Comment: please mention any code changes requires in his code @Ben Voigt